# Bootstrap Custom nav bar shape

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I want to make a custom nav bar shape like in the below attached image.

[image]

For this shape I have used the following CSS:

```
.navbar-nav.nav-bar-custom {
    transform: skew(-21deg);
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

But when I use this, all my text looks like it is italic. See the attached image.

[image]

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: please give the full code including html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a pseudo element for this. The pseudo selector is an element in itself, so it will not affect the content of the `<nav>`.

#### The HTML

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-color">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-dark my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

#### And the SCSS

```
.navbar {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.bg-color {
  padding: 10px 45px;
  &::before {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    transform: skew(-21deg);
    display: block;
    content: "";
    background-color: rgb(240, 140, 60);
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}
```

Or check the pen: https://codepen.io/aboutandre/pen/WmjENX

You can read more about *pseudo-elements* here on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).

Answer (score 0):

This is all because you have skewed the main container, so the complete conter is skewed including texts.

now to counter the effect for the texts you

Just reverse skew your text to

```
.textnav {
    transform: skew(20deg);
}
```

and add this class to all you texts and this will help you.

Comment: hope this will help you. and if need any further help just ask

Comment: I think this COULD be a good answer, as it's correct, but you should go into more depth how best to implement that, including asking OP for more information (including their code) so that you can answer this appropriately. I've +1'd in good faith you'll update this.

Comment: @NitinGarg. It's work. But skew(21deg) should be skew(-20deg);

Comment: You can also use `.navbar-nav.nav-bar-custom > *`